# How to set TCP_NODELAY and SO_KEEPALIVE with HttpClient 4.3

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

With Apache HttpClient 4.3 how do I turn off Nagle's algorithm (TCP_NODELAY) and turn on TCP keep-alive packets (SO_KEEPALIVE) without using the deprecated HttpParams?

Note: TCP keep-alive and HTTP keep-alive are two different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom()
        .setSoKeepAlive(true)
        .setTcpNoDelay(true)
        .build();
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
        .build();
```